# How to close colorbox window after submit, and refresh image on parent page?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I am using colorbox for a modal display, which opens for the user when clicking on an image to update it. Once the user uploads a new image and hits submit on the colorbox modal, the modal should close and refresh the image on the parent page.

I am using the following onClick event within the submit button:

```
  <input onClick='window.parent.location.reload(true);' type='submit' value='Submit' name='save_button' id='save_button'>
```

This closes the modal and refreshes the parent page.php. But for some reason, it does not refresh the old image to show the new image the user just uploaded.

**EDIT: Added Colorbox Code**

The script that calls the color box was conflicting with other javascript code, so I added the following script above the colorbox code, and changed the `$` to `jQuery` in the code:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("iframe").hide();
  });

  $('input').hide();
</script>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"748px", height:"92%"});
  });
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if it shows after Cntrl+F5 then the browser catch issues

Comment: Ctrl+F5 indeed refreshes the image along with the page. But so does the "Reload" (FireFox) function of the browser. Why wouldn't the image reload when the onClick event reloads the entire page?

Comment: browser creates a catch for faster browsing and if your image src[location] is same after your page refresh browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, specific to colorbox script, which ended up working for me. I added `onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true); }` in the last part of the script below:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("iframe").hide();
  });

  $('input').hide();
</script>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"748px", height:"92%", onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true); } });
  });
</script>
```

Then I added the onClick event inside the submit button code:

```
<input type='submit' value="Submit' onClick='parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();'>
```

This closes the colorbox modal while refreshing the parent page, along with the image for all current versions of FF, IE, Opera, and Chrome. It refreshes page, but not the image in Opera.

Answer (score 1):

The browser creates a cache for faster browsing and if your image src[location] is the same after your page refresh, the browser shows you the previous copy of the image. You have to change target of the the image src attribute each reload or do the same via a function, like this:

```
$('img').each(function(){
$(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src')+Datetime.now());
});
```

Comment: As a novice at javascript, I assume you meant to include the above script within <script> tags on the parent page, correct? If so, I tried, and it didn't work

Comment: this answer is dependant on you using jQuery as well as having a non-native DateTime object. It's not really compatible with vanilla javaScript.

Comment: jQuery is on the parent page. I assume you meant to include the script on the parent page. I did, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the image is cached in the browser, give your image control an ID and call `window.parent.document.getElementID("image").src += "?" + [some random number, or maybe the miliseconds];` this will cause it to go back to the server for and reload the image.

**EDIT**

more fleshed out script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function onSubmitClick(){
    parent.jQuery("#img")[0].src += "?" + Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);
    //note the above will append a random number between 0 and 1000 to the src.
    parent.jQuery.colorbox.close()
  }
</script>

<input onClick='onSubmitClick();' type='submit' value='Submit' name='save_button' id='save_button'>
<img src="pic.jpg" id="img">
```

I also realized a failing in my suggestion is that when the page is reloaded it's just going to load the same image from cache again. So this script is written without the page refresh.

Comment: I am a novice at javascript. Is this code meant to go in the <input> tag with the submit button inside an onClick event? Or should I put it on the parent page inside <script> tags? I tried both, and neither work.

Comment: change your input to `<input onClick="iptOnClick();" ...>` Then write a function `function iptOnClick(){window.parent.location.reload(true);window.parent.document.getElementID("image").src += "?" + [some random number, or maybe the miliseconds];}` so it will fire both as a function when you click your submit button

Comment: It refreshes page, just like `onClick='window.parent.location.reload(true);'`. But it doesn't refresh the image. When I use the browser's RELOAD function, the new image appears, however

Comment: Okay, what is the id of your image element? I'll write it out the script in further detail.

Comment: see edit. I also realized that refreshing is just going to load the image from cache again, is there a reason you are refreshing the page other than to just update the image?

Comment: I don't need to refresh anything except for the image. Refreshing only the image on the parent page is all that's needed. I also edited my original post to include the colorbox script.

Comment: It doesn't close the colorbox modal upon submit

Comment: I have not used color box, so I'm not entirely sure what the script to close it would be, from what I could find on a quick search, the line I just added should do it.

Comment: When adding `onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true); }` to the Colorbox code, when clicking the html `<a href=''>` link at the bottom of the modal, it refreshes the page, including the image. But when using `onClick='function(){ location.reload(true)};'` inside the input submit button, it doesn't close the modal.

Comment: you would still need to call `jQuery.colorbox.close()` in order to close the modal.

Comment: This closes the colorbox modal, but the page nor the image is refreshing

Comment: are you not doing both? `onClick='function(){ jQuery.colorbox.close(); location.reload(true)};'` If you are still having trouble, head here: http://jsfiddle.net/ and start a fiddle that mimics what you are doing so we can see exactly what your code is looking like.

Comment: @ invertedSpear, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately nothing worked except for the answer I posted. Thanks again for all your attempts.